# Number of Combinations for a Password

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am looking to find how many combinations of an $8$-$10$ character password there are with the following stipulations:

$1.$ There must be at least $1$ lower case letter.

$2.$ There must be exactly $1$ upper case letter.

$3.$ There must be exactly $2$ numbers.

$4.$ There must be exactly $1$ special characters. (There are $19$ options for the special characters)

I at first thought about using the complement of the set of all passwords in order to make stipulation $1.$ easier to deal with, but that obviously made all of the other stipulations harder to deal with. So then I started to brute force it, and that led to me getting an answer greater than $81^8+81^9+81^{10}$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Isn't the first condition redundant here? If there are e.g. $8$ characters then  it seems to me that there are exactly $8-4$ lower case letters.

Comment: What a silly mistake, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the password has $k\in\{8,9,10\}$ characters then there are $k$ possibilities for choosing the spot for the upper case letter; after that there are $k-1$ possibilities for choosing the spot of the special character; after that there are $\binom{k-2}2$ ways for choosing the spots of the numbers.

The remaining spots (there are more than $0$)  are for the lower case letters.

Based on this we find: $$k(k-1)\frac12(k-2)(k-3)\times26\cdot19\cdot10^2\cdot26^{k-4}$$possible passwords of length $k$.

Now find this for $k=8,9,10$ and take the summation of the numbers.

Comment: What about repetition of letters and how many times letters are repeated in a password e.g aaA11@ddd is also one of password these can be arranged only in 9!/2!2!3!

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com Do you agree that under e.g. the condition of the use of  exactly two lower case letters (and nothing else)  there are $26^2$ passwords? This in spite of the fact that e.g. word "pp" can only be arranged in one way?

Comment: The condition is atleast 1 lowercase to illustrate I have taken 2 lowercase. There are lot many variables hence not that easy to comment on number of password only 4 character in min 8 are fixed in that also numbers can be same.

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com Sorry but I do not really understand what you are trying to say. Is anything wrong my answer?